# What permission is required for a MySQL user to create a database?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for a user other than root to create a database?

```
 GRANT SELECT, CREATE ON *.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*12057DFA2BFBD8760D4788735B1C3E26889D7ECE' |
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine'
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2`.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine'
```

I wonder what privilege is missing here? Also, why does the first line have a password attached to it?

UPDATE

Let me further clarify what the point of my question is. I have two database machines, source and target. There are many customer databases on the source machine. I need to move those source databases to the other target machine.

The databases are in the form of mysqldump'ed .sql files, which are sftp'd from source to target. Target user, not root, must then recreate the databases locally from each .sql file, perform some actions, then drop the database.

I can't find a way to give these privileges to the target user without giving him global privileges on `*.*`, which effectively makes that user as dangerous as root.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, here's a thought. Instead of using mysql on the target machine, use an alternate database specifically for this transaction. SQLite, or something along those lines. This way, his permissions have nothing to do with any fully operational database, they can only be used with and for the temporary database and actions. You may have to change some scripts, or what not, but you will be much safer this way. Make a small pocket of control, for this specific feat, and then nullify it when he's done. Might be some extra work - but it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely you can.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

Comment: In a really unfortunate chain of events, the user 'myguy' is indeed allowed to create databases. He just can't destroy them.

And yet, I don't want that user to be able to destroy databases that he did not create, so what privilege do I give him? Why is this so hard?

Comment: @AKWF: Hmph. That is indeed ... unfortunate. You may want to specifically grant him `DROP` privilege for databases he created, right after he creates them; AFAIK this is not possible to do automatically in MySQL. Is he creating the databases through a script, or do you have no control over his actions?

Comment: What you need to do is decide what exactly you want this particular user to be able to do, then grant them those permissions. For example, according to this, he has all privileges on db1 and db2 and he can select and create on ALL databases, but apparently cannot update or insert... odd setup I would say. But if you just want him to have read and update only, then you would do something like this:
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*12057DFA2BFBD8760D4788735B1C3E26889D7ECE'

Comment: A user that is able to create a database should automatically have full control over the databases he has created, without the need for explicit privileges on those databases. But if this isn't the way MySQL works, I suppose I could grant privileges on the database names before they are created. MySQL allows this, doesn't it?

Comment: @AKWF A bit late, but give `myguy` permissions to create and destroy databases named `myguy_*` (or % or whatever the mysql wildcard was)

Comment: @AKWF @Izkata: If you want the person to have full control over a narrow swath of the system, you can use:

`grant all privileges on 'myguy_%'.* to myguy@localhost identified by 'password';`

(Replace the quotes around myguy_% with backticks - it was a limitation in mini-Markdown formatting.)

Comment: @EvanDonovan im turning that into an answer like it should be

Answer (score 3):

As Izkata and Evan Donovan have mentioned in the comments, the best way to achieve this is to give `myguy` all privileges on the database `myguy_%`.

You can do this with the following sql:

```
grant all privileges on 'myguy_%'.* to myguy@localhost identified by 'password';
```

This way you don't have to bother with other existing databases, and `myguy` is able to create new databases to his heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

The password field is what that particular user's password is when logging into MySQL itself. I'm not exactly sure what you mean when you say you wonder what privileges are missing. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a user that must download .sql db dumps and restore them on a local system. I don't know what the names of those databases are going to be in advance, so I had to give "create on *.*" to the user. I thought it would be common sense that a user that created a database would be able to drop it, but no such luck. I don't dare give the user "drop on *.*", this is a web application for Pete's sake. I just want to secure this database user and enable them to do some things, but limit any potential damage if the user was ever hijacked.

Comment: For web apps, it's good practice to not allow the creation or dropping of anything unless you know that that person knows exactly what they're doing - for example, in the use of PHPMyAdmin.
Also, you may want to consider a database scheme wherein the creation of entire databases is not a necessary. I see very few examples where an end user needs to be able to create an entire database.

Comment: Even at that - really ... you should never drop/delete anything, just use a boolean 'deleted' field.