# What mysql privilege allows creating schema when you are not root?

Tags: mysql

I am not able to create new schema in mySQL getting access denied. I am not root so I need to ask for more privileges which I am not sure what I should exactly ask for.

**SHOW GRANTS FOR 'saher'@'localhost';**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for saher@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'saher'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2472DEC52D39F7EBB1C860FF69436F8E08540F9A' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> **CREATE SCHEMA torrentScrape;**

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'saher'@'localhost' to database 'torrentScrape'

Can I tell root to do the following?
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'saher'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934447/what-permission-is-required-for-a-mysql-user-to-create-a-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the CREATE privilege. Note that CREATE SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

Comment: can you just use the following command instead: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'saher'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Sure, granting all privileges would work, but I wouldn't recommend doing that in a production environment. Try `GRANT CREATE` first.