# show only selected database for phpmyadmin user

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have one issue with phpmyadmin user, i have one new user and i want to assign specific database for access and view, i mean i have 5 database in phpmyadmin and i want to show only specific database for other user so its cant be view other database and not able to access them

i try with

> On the phpMyAdmin default page (localhost) click on the "Privileges" link
>   Click on the "Add a new User link"
>   Assign the User a login and password
>   Where it says "Database for User" select "None"
>   Leave all checkboxes in global privileges unchecked
>   Press the "Go" button

but using this user can view all the database

Comment: there are access setting you need to give the permission as required

Answer (score 3):

Create the user with only that database permission.

```
grant all on `db_name.*` to `'username'@'localhost'`;
```

[For details Information Click Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/2616/which-mysql-users-have-access-to-a-database)

Comment: in db_name you have to give database name which you want to show.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck this options from the user account
http://prntscr.com/ev00v2

For further details check document 
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html

I am not sure but maybe it will help you to solve your query

[What permission is required for a MySQL user to create a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934447/what-permission-is-required-for-a-mysql-user-to-create-a-database)

```
 GRANT SELECT, CREATE ON *.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*12057DFA2BFBD8760D4788735B1C3E26889D7ECE' |
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myguy'@'thatmachine'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

Comment: this is not an answer. please provide better description not link.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the db when you create the user. This ensures the user only has access to that db.